# How to remove a certain portion of the column name in a dataframe?

Tags: r, gsub

I have column names in the following format:

```
col= c('UserLanguage','Q48','Q21...20','Q22...21',"Q22_4_TEXT...202")
```

I would like to get the column names without everything that is after ...

```
[1] "UserLanguage"    "Q48"             "Q21"        "Q22"        "Q22_4_TEXT"
```

I am not sure how to code it. I found this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61481713/remove-part-from-middle-of-column-names-in-r) but I am not sure how to specify the pattern in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gsub`.

```
gsub("\\...*","",col)

#[1] "UserLanguage" "Q48"     "Q21"        "Q22"     "Q22_4_TEXT"
```

Or you can use `stringr`

```
library(stringr)

str_remove(col, "\\...*")
```

Since `.` matches any character, we need to "escape" (`\`) to specify exactly what we want to match in the regular expression (and not use the special behavior of the `.`). So, to match a period, we would need `\.`. However, the backslash (`\`) is used to escape special behavior (e.g., escape symbol in strings) in regexps. So, to create the regular expression, we need an additional backslash, `\\.` In this case, we want to match additional periods, so we can add those here, hence `\\...`. Then, `*` specifies that the previous expression (everything the three periods) may occur 0 or more times.

Comment: thank you, can you explain why I need extra .? and why two  \\ is needed?

Comment: @yuliaUU You're welcome. I added more of description at the bottom. Also, it should have just been 3 periods and not 4 (though 2 would also work in this case as well).

Answer (score 1):

You could `sub` and capture the first word in each column:

```r
col <- c("UserLanguage", "Q48", "Q21...20", "Q22...21", "Q22_4_TEXT...202")
sub("^(\\w+).*$", "\\1", col)

[1] "UserLanguage" "Q48"          "Q21"          "Q22"          "Q22_4_TEXT"
```

The regex pattern used here says to match:

```regex
^      from the start of the input
(\w+)  match AND capture the first word
.*     then consume the rest
$      end of the input
```

Then, using `sub` we replace with `\1` to retain just the first word.

Comment: thank you Tim! can you explain the logic behind \\w+ ?

Comment: @yuliaUU Added a description.  We need to use `\\w+` rather than `\w+` as backslash itself is an escape character and must be escaped.